# Cannot drag tables from Server Explorer to .edmx designer pane

Tags: entity-framework

Why can't I drag tables from the Server Explorer to the .edmx designer pane? I've done this before in the exact same steps and it worked, but since yesterday instead of getting the classic + sign for dropping items, I get the no entry symbol (circle with slash in the middle).

What am I doing wrong? As I said, I've done this before but now it doesn't let me drag things.
[image]

Comment: have you solved the problem or still need help @sergio Tapia

Answer (score 9):

Please don't take this the wrong way but are you absolutely sure :)? Linq to SQL supports drag-and-drop via the Server Explorer but as far as I'm aware the only way to do this sort of thing in Entity Framework is by choosing the "Update Model from Database..." context menu option and picking your tables from the list.

I'm assuming here that you're using Entity Framework based on your saying ".edmx" (Linq to SQL uses the .dbml format).

Comment: That's correct. I believe we can drag and drop from the Server Explorer initially but not once the Entity Framework has been created. After that, we need to use the Update Model from Database.

Comment: I don't believe EF has any support for interaction with the Server Explorer whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Seems too late but may be this help somebody:

> Ensure that the table you're trying to drag has Primary Key defined!

This is how I ended up getting tables in diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error, after some research i found that this problem is there if you are using SQL Server 2012 with VS2010 , refer following links...

Unable to update DBML: The specified module could not be loaded
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/linqtosql/thread/78537f25-6c45-4b56-b476-992e7fe8b4bf

Visual Studio Database Tools Error
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc/

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\dsref80.dll OR C:\Program File\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\dsref80.dll`.
2. Search for the same file on another computer that has Visual Studio 2010 installed working properly. Copy this file from that computer, and paste it in the same location on your computer.

And enjoy. It will work. I tried and got access.